# Дженерики и связь типов

Tags: java

Добрый день.

*У меня, как у человека, привыкшего к C++ и шаблонам, постоянно возникают какие-то недопонимания с дженериками.*

Итак, предположим, у нас есть принтеры, которые умеют печатать некоторые объекты:

```
public interface Printer<X> { 
    public void print(X obj); 
}
```

Есть список, на каком принтере и что надо напечатать:

```
class PrintInfo<X> { 
    public Printer<X> printer; 
    public X obj; 
}

Queue<PrintInfo<?>> q;
```

Ттеперь хочется начать печатать:

```
PrintInfo<?> pi = q.poll(); 
pi.printer.print(pi.obj); // FAIL
```

Проблема в том, что Джава почему-то в упор не видит, что это корректный вызов, хотя связь типов, вроде бы, очевидна. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит, и какие есть варианты обхода?

---

P.S. Я обошёл, добавив в `PrintInfo` метод `print`, который, собственно, печатает свой объект на своём принтере, и вызываю его.

Comment: Они у вас совершенно верно возникают.

Comment: @Александр Кашпировский такое ощущение, что Вы меня гипнотизируете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно не видит. Это из-за "?". Вы пытаетесь взять неизвестность и напечатать её с помощью неизвестного принтера. Но две разные неизвестности не всегда совместимы.

Возможно, это ошибка дизайна. Лично мне кажется, что генерики здесь ни к чему.

UPD

ОК. Возможно я немного погорячился :)

Вообще, если не хочется переделывать, то вы можете спрятать печать внутрь джобы

```
public class PrintTask<T extends Printable> {
    private final PrintStrategy<T> strategy;
    private final T object;

    public PrintTask(PrintStrategy<T> strategy, T object) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
        this.object = object;
    }

    public final void print() {
        strategy.print(object);
    }

}
```

И тогда можно будет просто делать

```
do {
    queue.take().print();
} while (....);
```

Comment: Да, это я понимаю. Но, казалось бы, в PrintInfo содержится достаточно информации, чтобы гарантировать, что эти две неизвестности не могут быть разными типами…

Comment: Но туда тоже подставляется "?"

Comment: Ой как глупо :(. Да, сегодня утром это выглядит гораздо очевиднее, чем выглядело вчера вечером… Верните мне обратно мой C++, в котором такие штуки без проблем работают!

Comment: Вообще, конечно же, это минимальный пример, и в реально задаче нет никаких принтеров, но я, вроде как, довольно точно передал суть происходящего, так что готов обсудить идею с ошибкой в архитектуре (честно говоря, интерфейс, соответствующий принтеру, дан изначально, так что у меня нет возможности переделать архитектуру в этом месте, но просто из спортивного интереса). Как сделать без дженериков?

Comment: Да, как я написал в PS, именно так я и поступил ;). Спасибо.